# How do I change elements text in HTML (Using <script>>

Tags: html

How do i change Result to 'IDK MAN' in `<script>`

```
<p class="card-text">
    Result = 'Success'

    <script>
          document.body.Result.textContent = 'TEST'
    </script>
</p>
```

Comment: Do you want to paste your code here?

Comment: @MonsieurVolt it didn't work; it just wont work :C

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov ok

Comment: I gave you the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You need to communicate with tags `<p>`, class `card-text` using `document.querySelector()`. Like here:

```
let tag_p = document.querySelector('.card-text');
```

2 - Using `textContent` and the declared `variable`, we insert the text content instead of the current one:

```
tag_p.textContent = 'TEST';
```

If you have any questions, please let me know.

```js
let tag_p = document.querySelector('.card-text');
tag_p.textContent = 'TEST';
```

```html
<p class="card-text">
  Result = 'Success'
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to select your `card-text` paragraph :

```
<script>
    document.getElementByClassName("card-text").innerHTML = "IDK MAN"
</script>
```